# How to recompile libgnome-shell.so

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-shell

How would one recompile `libgnome-shell.so`?

The `getShell` scirpt extracts the resources from `lib-gnome-shell.so` and puts them in `$HOME/GNOME_SHELL`.

**getShell**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# found this script and modified it a bit, original:
# https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/03/24/keeping-gnome-shell-approachable/

gs=/usr/lib/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so

mkdir $HOME/GNOME_SHELL

cd $HOME/GNOME_SHELL

mkdir -p ui/components ui/status misc perf extensionPerfs gdm portalHelper

for r in `gresource list $gs`; do
  gresource extract $gs $r > ${r/#\/org\/gnome\/shell/.}
done
```

Now I can edit the `libgnome-shell.so` resources but how do I put it back together?

Tried the following.

**buildShell**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# found this script and modified it a bit, orginal:
# https://github.com/devpytech/scripts/tree/master/gresource-extract/build.sh

FILES=$(find "$HOME/GNOME_SHELL" -type f -printf "%P\n" | xargs -i echo "    <file>{}</file>")

cat <<EOF >"$HOME/GNOME_SHELL/libgnome-shell.so.xml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/org/gnome/shell">
$FILES
  </gresource>
</gresources>
EOF

(
  cd "$HOME/GNOME_SHELL"
  glib-compile-resources --target=libgnome-shell.so libgnome-shell.so.xml
)
```

When I moved the newly created `libgnome-shell.so` to `/usr/lib/gnome-shell/` and rebooted, my system got stuck right before launching the display manager.

Not sure if this is the right way of recompiling `libgnome-shell.so`, had to try it though.

Found a couple of questions/answers suggesting to not recompile it but to link to the extracted (edited) resources, using `G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS` or `GNOME_SHELL_JS` variable. See [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1387159/libgnome-shell-so-extract-change-content-in-some-files-and-compile-back-is-it) answered by @grawity. Tried these but did not work for me.

**System:** a VM with Ubuntu server 18.04, gdm3 and gnome-session.

Comment: I have seen the same thread that you linked, and could at least make the G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS thing to work. Here are the details: https://askubuntu.com/a/1317692/1157519 I have found your question seeking the way to re-compile :)